# How do I properly set up these determination rules for my Player vs Computer Dice Game?

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, methods, do-while

I must set up a Player vs Computer Dice Game, consisting of 3 dice to each, which upon roll will determine which "player" has won the round. There are several determination factors (rules) with which I'm struggling to efficiently input.

- A Triple is when all the dice have the same number, the value of the Triple is their common value. (This I know is ((d1 == d2) && (d1 == d3))
- A Pair is when two of the dice have the same number, the value of the pair is the common value. (Similar to triple but with || I believe)
- Junk is anything that is not a Triple or Pair.
- Any Triple beats any Pair.
- Any Triple beats any Junk.
- Two Triples are compared by their respective values.
- Any Pair beats and Junk.
- Two Pairs are first compared by their respective pair values, and then by their respective non-common die values.

If it was a couple determinations I wouldn't have a problem with it but I'm kinda lost due to the fact that we need all these conditions to check each roll-loop and I was told to only use the main class.

I believe I've correctly set up the entire program *ASIDE FROM DETERMINATION* and can get values each roll, counters working and such. The issue lies in inputing the determination rules into the game. Everything else I feel confident in working through.

This is my DO-WHILE loop for the roll and determination area. As you can see I'm struggling with how to manage and input the determinations.
I get the basic idea that it is a 3! situation resulting in 6 combinations but I don't understand how to compare Player and Computer values properly.
In class I was given a tip... 
- math library
- int d1, d2, d3;

- int big = Math.max(Math.max(d1,d2),d3)
- int small = Math.min(Math.min(d1,d2),d3)
- int medium = (d1 + d2 + d3) - (b + s)

This is to check values on the dice. I understand how this works but I've lost the plot as to how this will work with a Player and Computer both having 3 dice and using these integer variables with Determination rules.

```
do
        {   
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do you wish to play again? [y, n]");
            answer = stdIn.next();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
            {
                turnCounter++;

                System.out.println("Player");
                System.out.println("------");
                int d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                System.out.println("Roll: " + "\t" + d1 + "\t" + d2 + "\t" + d3 + "\n");
                System.out.println("Computer");
                System.out.println("--------");
                int d4 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int d5 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int d6 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                System.out.println("Roll: " + "\t" + d4 + "\t" + d5 + "\t" + d6);

                if ((d1 == d2) && (d1 == d3) && 
                    (d4 == d5) && (d4 == d6)) //Triple (Player & Computer) Tie
                    roundTied++;
                    System.out.println("You tied the round with the Computer!");
                if ((d1 == d2) || (d2 == d3) || (d1 == d3) && 
                    (d4 == d5) || (d4 == d6) || d5 == d6) //Pair (Player & Computer) Tie
                    roundTied++;
                    System.out.println("You tied the round with the Computer!");
                if ()

                if (userWin > compWin) winner = Player;}

                if (compWin > userWin) winner = Computer;

        }while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
            System.out.println("\n" + "Game Results");
            System.out.println("------------");
            System.out.println("Rounds Played: " + turnCounter);
            System.out.println("User Wins: " + userWin + "\t" + " User Losses: " + userLoss);
            System.out.println("Computer Wins: " + compWin + "\t" + "Computer Losses: " + compLoss);
            System.out.println("Rounds Tied: " + roundTied);
            System.out.println("------------");
            System.out.println("The " + winner + " has won the game!");
            stdIn.close();
```

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of "if... if... if..." and start thinking in terms of "if... else if... else". All of your determination rules are mutually exclusive, so once you have satisfied a condition, there's no need to check further conditions. Work from the general (most common/least restrictive) cases (like "junk") to the specific (least common/most restrictive) like trips. I advise you to stop looking at Stack Overflow and just think about your task given what I've written. You're going to learn a ton more if you just do it yourself from here.

Comment: Also, for player vs. computer, think of the dice as two sets of three dice each rather than as six separate dice. You can create an object to represent three rolled dice if that helps your thinking.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will take your input into careful consideration and try to take it one rule at a time. I like the idea of two sets and thought about implementing it.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @MarsAtomic So I took your advice and finished the program... However, there's one final issue I'm struggling to resolve and I was wondering if you had a tip. When determining a winner of the round, sometimes if a pair or triple is present, the code is only recognizing the high die as opposed to the former. EX. Player: (1,1,1) Computer: (1,1,2). I was curious as to how to fix this. The program is error free and looks good but misses this final condition.

Comment: Without seeing your new code, it's hard to say, but the general strategy is: if player has trips, he's only going to lose if the computer also has trips, so that's the first thing you check. If comp has trips, the winner is whoever has the stronger set, else tie.Extend this logic for the other cases (player has pair, player has junk). For your (1,1,1) vs (1,1,2) case, if you've structured your "if... else if... else" statements properly, you'll never see that problem.

Comment: Just so you know, the exercise is trying to get you to think like an engineer, and involves categorizing all outcomes into manageable groups and then making decisions based on those groups: 1) Player has trips 2) Player has pair 3) Player has junk. Compare each of those to all outcomes for the computer (same three). Remember that some outcomes don't matter because they lead to the same place, e.g. computer has trips, player has lower trips, player has pair, player has junk all lead to a player loss, so once you've checked for trips, all other outcomes are moot.